# Using pointers as function parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

I want to do a function that uses pointers a s parameters and return one of the pointers, is it possible?

Example:

```
int* sum(int* x, int* y, int* total){
    total=x+y;
    return total;
}
```

I get this error:

```
main.cpp:10:13: error: invalid operands of types 'int*' and 'int*' to binary 'operator+'
```

How can I do that using only pointers and not references?

Comment: Try `*total = *x + *y` (and as a side note, both the x and y pointers should be const, or in-fact not even pointers in this example).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereferencing

Comment: I almost fainted when I see this.

Comment: @texasbruce: Everyone starts somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this worked (it doesn't compile, rightly so):

```
 total=x+y;
```

it would give you the pointer that points at the address of `x` + the address of `y`. Since this is [nearly] always nonsense, the compiler doesn't allow you to add two pointers together.

What you really want is to add the value that `int *x` and `int *y` POINTS AT, and store it in the place that `total` points at:

```
*total = *x + *y;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference the pointers to return a reference to the object they point to:

```
*total = *x + *y;
```

However, in C++ you can use references to facilitate this:

```
int sum(int x, int y, int& total)
{
    total = x + y;
    return total;
}
```

The reference is only declared with `total` because that is the only argument we need to change. Here's an example of how you would go about calling it:

```
int a = 5, b = 5;
int total;

sum(a, b, total);
```

Now that I think of it, since we're using references to change the value, there really isn't a need to return. Just take out the return statement and change the return type to `void`:

```
void sum(int x, int y, int& total)
{
    total = x + y;
}
```

Or you can go the other way around and return the addition without using references:

```
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```